# Where Do Bootcamp Utilities Install?

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp

In my Snow Leopard installation, I was unable to pull the BootCamp Windows tools down with the Bootcamp utility.

I downloaded them from [here](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p682/download-bootcamp-drivers) and installed them, but, I have no idea where they installed and so I am unsure where the exe files I need to install on the Windows side are.

What file is installed by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is called

```
windowssupport.dmg
```

There are no easily viewable exe files which can be searched for - this must be opened, and all the files required on the Windows side are located in this folder.

It appears to be installed in `Library/Application Support/Bootcamp/` as well.